# Should I be removing the zero for "0.9", so that it becomes ".9"?

Tags: numbers, formatting

Am I supposed to remove the "0" for any decimal number which is 0.something? For example:

`.9` instead of `0.9`

Or:

`.45` instead of `0.45`

?

Is this a general rule in English? Perhaps also in other languages? I think I've seen it a lot in older adverts and stuff like that, but should it be done generally? Doesn't it just add confusion?

It *does* look slightly better visually...

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: In written text the zero is preferred, since it helps the reader properly interpret the number.  In speech it is sometimes omitted.

Comment: Are you asking about in speech or in writing?

Comment: If you're writing an article for publication, their style guide should tell you how to write such numbers.